# Determine how each feature contribute to XGBoost Classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, xgboost

so for a summary of what I have done:

My dataset has 5 classes and 10 parameters. I used XGBclassifer from sklearn to investigate if I could use those 10 parameters to predict the class of each data point. After training and fitting the XGBclassifier, I checked feature_importances_ and found out that 2/10 parameters played a key role in the classification.

So my question is:

Can I find out exactly how those 2 parameters contribute to the classification of each specific class? For example, can I find the cut-off values for parameter 1 and parameter 2 that will result in the prediction of class 1?

I am thinking of performing unsupervised clustering using those 2 parameters and k value = 5. Afterwards, I can just eyeball the approximate cutoff values. However, I worry that the 5 clusters will not correspond closely to the 5 groups.

Thanks a lot in advanced

Answer (score 1):

If you have just then parameters and two of them are important. You can plot the trees and see the threshold for each of the parameters.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fit the model 
model = XGBClassifier().fit(X, y)
# plot single tree
plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

The above code just plots the first tree. You can plot, for example, 4th boosted tree in sequences using the following line of code

```
plot_tree(model, num_trees=3)
```

Note that in each tree, you might have a different threshold for each parameter in an ensembling method.

Answer (score 1):

I think `shap values` might be able to help you. Check this out [link](https://github.com/slundberg/shap). You can check both local as well as global interpretability.